# Convert a list of tuples(edges) into list of longest paths in Python

Tags: python, graph, tree

Please look at the fig. below. As a part of my project, I am in need to convert a list of edges of a forest into a list of unique longest paths. The longest paths are actually paths which connect any root node to a leaf node or a leaf to a leaf node. The problem here is, I have only the list of edges as an input, from which, I am supposed to derive these paths.

I am trying to solve this problem recursively by looking for neighbor nodes using a dictionary(created using the list of edges), but it looks like it is not the proper way to handle the problem and also i am finding to hard to visualize. Please suggest if there is any known efficient algorithms/methods to solve this problem.

**P.S.:** Please neglect the weights(they are just labels). **"Longest"** means the path covering maximum nodes.

**Input:**
*List of Tuples(edges)*

```
edges = [('point', 'floating'), ('754', 'floating'),
('clock', 'IEEE'), ('ARM', 'barrel'), 
('barrel', 'shifter clock'), ('shifter', 'barrel'), 
('representation', 'representation'), ('cycles', '754'), 
('point representation', 'point'), ('barrel shifter', 'point')]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
inference_paths = [
    ['cycles', '754', 'floating', 'point', 'point representation'],
    ['cycles', '754', 'floating', 'point', 'barrel shifter'],
    ['point repr', 'point', 'barrel shifter'],
    ['ARM', 'barrel', 'shifter clock'],
    ['shifter', 'barrel', 'shifter clock'],
    ['ARM', 'barrel', 'shifter'],
    ['clock', 'IEEE'],
    ['representation']
]
```

**My failed code:**

```
edges = [('point', 'floating'), ('754', 'floating'), ('clock', 'IEEE'), ('ARM', 'barrel'), ('barrel', 'shifter clock'), ('shifter', 'barrel'), ('representation', 'representation'), ('cycles', '754'), ('point representation', 'point'), ('barrel shifter', 'point')]
neighbors = {}
inference_paths = []

for edge in edges:
    neighbors[edge[0]] = edge[1]

for edge in edges:
    neighbor = neighbors.get(edge[1])
    if neighbor:
        if not edge[1] == edge[0] == neighbor:
            inference_paths.append([edge[0], edge[1], neighbor])
        else:
            inference_paths.append([edge[0]])
    else:
        inference_paths.append([edge[0], edge[1]])


for path in inference_paths:
    print path
```

**My Output:**

```
[['point', 'floating'],
['754', 'floating'],
['clock', 'IEEE'],
['ARM', 'barrel', 'shifter clock'],
['barrel', 'shifter clock'],
['shifter', 'barrel', 'shifter clock'],
['representation'],
['cycles', '754', 'floating'],
['point representation', 'point', 'floating'],
['barrel shifter', 'point', 'floating']]
```

**Forest:**

[image]

Comment: Given the question this image confuses me.  There is only one path from any given leaf node, to it's root.  The question suggests the problem is more difficult than simply tree traversal.  Perhaps you should post a more complex diagram.

Comment: @ChrisCM Basically, the inference paths are paths connecting any two nodes. By mining the longest paths, it is easier to represent each tree as a set of minimum number of inference paths. As per the fig. above, Tree-1 has 3 inference paths and these paths can cover all possible links between any nodes. There are 4 Trees in this forest in total(as in Fig.)

Comment: So the answer you would want from the far left tree, for example is .74 + .77 as the longest possible path, to any of floatings leaf nodes, which happens to be the cycles leaf.  Am I interpreting the problem correctly?

Comment: @ChrisCM Please neglect the weights(they are just labels). Here I mean Longest in the sense "Covering maximum nodes". Consider the tree to be undirected acyclic unweighted.

Comment: Yes, I saw your PS: ignore weights thing.  All makes sense now!  I am drumming up an answer now, I'm not versed in python, so it will be psueduo code instead.  But you seem to have the python part down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is, you say you're using recursion, but you're not.  Attempting to do this iteratively is painful.  First lets look at a basic recursive tree traversal function.

```
function traverseTree(node) {
    if(node == NULL) return;
    traverseTree(node->leftSubTree);
    traverseTree(node->rightSubTree);
}
```

The above function will visit all nodes in a tree, now we just have to figure out what logic we need calculate to figure out paths and such.  Note: your answers appear to suggest that a given node can only be used once in a path and cannot be crossed again, this assumption is used.

```
arrayOfPaths;
function traverseTree(node) {
    if(node == NULL) return emptyPathObject;

    leftPathObject = traverseTree(node->leftSubTree);
    rightPathObject = traverseTree(node->rightSubTree);
    arrayOfPaths.add(leftPathObject + node + rightPathObject);
    return ((node + leftPathObject) or (node + rightPathObject) whichever is longer);
}

//Code to figure out which paths are the longest here.  This is simpler than the other one too! :)
```

Comment: The solution as it is now, I like.  What do you think?

Comment: I still quite didn't get your solution. Would be helpful, if you can explain in a perspective w.r.t edges. Anyways thanks!

Comment: It's pretty simple really.  Use tree traversal to build up all possible paths.  Add finished "paths" to the array.  And unwind the call stack, by returning the longest of the sub paths.

Comment: Edges don't matter.  Since the "weight" of an edge doesn't matter, we don't care about the edges.  A path with the most nodes also has the most edges.  With the weighout of the question, they are the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot. "(node->leftSubTree)" Can you what does the arrow denote here?

Comment: The arrow is a C++ syntax thing.  It means that leftSubTree is a member of the "node" object.  Which in turn is another object of type "node".